# Magento2: How to change store view during mass edit products

Tags: magento2, translate, category-description

I have try bulk translate description products.

1) When I open single product "edit" then I can switch store view and add separate language to each store view:
[image]

But when I try to select and translate  bulk products from "Catalogue":
[image]

Impossible select from here store view. When I translate from here description product from English to Polish then translate as default (for every store view).

Any slotuion ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have first to select the products you want to change in the grid. Then, when you select your bulk action 'update attributes' you will see a screen with all the products attributes and also you will see the store view selector.

See screenshot below:

[image]